# Should I assert or throw an exception in a junit library?

Tags: java, junit

I'm writting a java library to easily write some junit tests. I don't know if I must assert inside my library or throw an exception. Here is an example. Asuming I define, in my library, this function to check the number of methods of class

```
public void assertNumberOfMethods(Class clazz, int expectedNumberOfMethods) {
     int numberOfMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods().length;
     //TODO compare number and expected number
}
```

Should I

1. Directly assert inside my library

   ```
   Assert.assertTrue(expectedNumberofMethod > 0); 
   Assert.assertEquals(numberOfMethods,expectedNumberOfMethods);
   //...
   ```
2. Throw an exception an let the user handle this exception. Since this library is designed to be used in unit tests, the user will be able to catch some of this exception using `@Test(expected=SomeCustomException.class)`

   ```
   public void assertNumberOfMethods(Class clazz, int expectedNumberOfMethods)  throws IllegalArgumentException, SomeCustomException {
       if(expectedNumberOfMethods <= 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(/*...*/);

       int numberOfMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods().length;

       if(numberOfMethods != expectedNumberOfMethods)
           throw new SomeCustomException(/*...*/);
   }
   ```

**EDIT** This is a dummy example

Comment: I wonder what the `SomeCustomException` would be called. Will you create a different `Exception` for every single one of your methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are planning to create specialized assert methods, like as you would write an extension to the `Assert` class.

For this you should directly throw assert errors (variant 1), as the assert methods in `Assert`do, providing a helpful error message.

The possibility to specify expected exceptions in the `@Test` annotation serves a different purpose. With this annotation Junit allows you to test that a piece of code throws an expected exception, without the need in the test code to catch the exception.

Comment: And if the tested code **doesn't** throw the expected exception, the test counts as failed.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the junit `fail()` method that is used in pretty much all other assert methods in the `junit` library

```
public void assertNumberOfMethods(Class clazz, int expectedNumberOfMethods) {
    int numberOfMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods().length;
    if (numberOfMethods != expectedNumberOfMethods) {
        fail("some failing message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `fail`, specifically? Why not make use of `assertEquals` (etc), so you can provide the custom message *and* get the arguments in the message automatically?

Comment: with `fail()` he has the possibility to use his own completely custom fail message. When using `assertEquals`, he has not. (only part of the error message can be customized)
If this is not needed, using an assert method, would of course suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You should throw a `java.lang.AssertionError` exception if an assertion is false.

Also, try not to re-invent the wheel, take a look at [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) which does exactly what you want.

```
// Example
assertThat(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()).hasSize(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to AssertJ, but I used a dummy example

Answer (score 1):

`expectedNumberofMethod > 0` should be an `IllegalArgumentException`. The test has not failed, the method has been called incorrectly.

`numberOfMethods == expectedNumberOfMethods` should throw a `java.lang.AssertionError` (or a like), how you do this is up to you, you could use `Assert.assertThat`, but it binds you to a test framework. You could throw it directly, but you have to do more manual work.

If you use `Assert.assertThat`, remember that the first argument can be a `String` description of what went wrong. Use it.

Don't use custom exceptions (that do not extent `java.lang.AssertionError`), think about what the users of your API will be expecting, and do that. Every other `assert` causes a `java.lang.AssertionError` to be throw, but you are doing something different.

Comment: _first argument can be a String_ I know, i removed it in order to simplify my code. Thanks for the details about `AssertionError `